# Returning lastInsertId() from database class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using a database class picked up from a tutorial on codecourse.com (I am just starting the migration from procedural to pdo) and I am slowly extending it to fit my needs. However, the one thing I cannot manage is to return the lastInsertId() to be used globally.

Using the register example from that tutorial

```
$user = new User();
$salt = Hash::salt(32);
try {
 $user->create(array(
  'username' => Input::get('username'),
  'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
  'salt' => $salt,
  'firstname' => Input::get('first_name'),
  'lastname' => Input::get('last_name'),
  'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'group' => 1
  ));
 } catch(Exception $e) {
   die($e->getMessage());
 }
```

It is at this point that I want to get the lastInsertId() - the one of the just registered user. I am not sure whether it comes out of the Database class via the insert function

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

class DB {
 private static $_instance = null;
 private $_pdo,
         $_query,
         $_error = false,
         $_results,
         $_count = 0;

 private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),  Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password') );

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}


public function query ($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
      }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function action ($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if (count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value = $where[2];

        if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get ($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}

public function delete ($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);

}

public function insert ($table, $fields = array()) {

        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }

            $x++;
        }


        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`,`', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if (!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        echo $sql;
   }
    return false;

}

public function update ($table, $id, $fields = array()) {

        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

       foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if ($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }

            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if (!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

     }
    return false;

}


public function first () {
    return $this->results()[0];
}

public function results () {
    return $this->_results;
}

public function count () {
    return $this->_count;
}

public function error () {
    return $this->_error;
}

}
```

Or the User class via the create function

```
class User {
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $_isLoggedIn;
public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');
    if (!$user) {
        if (Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);
            if ($this->find($user)) {
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                //Logged out
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->find($user);
    }
}
public function update($fields=array(), $id = null) {
    if (!$id && $this->isLoggedIn ()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }
    if (!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem updating the account!');
    }
}
public function create($fields) {
    if (!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account!');
    }
}
 public function find($user=null) {
    if ($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
        if ($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public function login($username=null, $password=null, $remember = false) {
    if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id );
    } else {
        $user = $this->find($username);
        if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
            if ($remember) {
                $hash = Hash::unique();
                $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
                if (!$hashCheck->count()) {

                    $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                         'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                        'hash' => $hash
                    ));
                } else {
                    $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                }
                Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
}
public function hasPermission ($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));
    if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);
        if ($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public function exists () {
    return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
}
public function logout () {
    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
}
public function data () {
    return $this->_data;
}
 public function isLoggedIn () {
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;
}
}
```

I have tried in both but whenever I try to echo the lastInsertId() back out, nothing is returned. Any advice would be greatly welcomed. If the problem might be outside of these areas, I have uploaded the entire script to https://github.com/MargateSteve/login.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Where are you trying to pull the PDO::lastInsertId() from, in the DB class?

Comment: I have tried it both in the DB class and the User class. The last attempt was in insert() in DB, creating an $ins_id variable and making it global.

`public function insert ($table, $fields = array()) {
     global $ins_id;
         $keys = array_keys($fields);
         $values = '';
         $x = 1;
         foreach($fields as $field) {
             // etc
          }
          $sql = "xxx";
          if (!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()) {
             return true;
          }
   $ins_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
            return false;
}`

Comment: I think you need to do it on the query function right after $this->_query->execute(), then call the lastInsertId() PDO function, save it to a variable on your DB instance and then you can access it in the User class with $this->_db->lastInsertId or whatever you called it

Comment: No joy alas. I added the following  in the query function as suggested
`if($this->_query->execute()) {
   $this->_insertID = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();` and am trying to call it in the page with `echo $user->insertID;` but it is returning blank.

Comment: It is working for me, I checked out your code on github and did some tests, please see my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a public variable to your `DB` class that will hold the last inserted record ID:

```
class DB {
    public $lastInsertId = null;
```

In the same `DB` class modify the query method, where the actual insert happens so that you can grab the ID from PDO:

```
public function query ($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->lastInsertId = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

On the code above this is the important line:

```
$this->lastInsertId = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
```

You are assigning the value of `PDO::lastInsertId()` to your `lastInsertId` instance variable, that way you can access it from wherever you instantiate a `DB` object.

Now, modify the user class to hold a variable called `id` as well, do not name it `lastInsertId`  because its confusing; in this context you have one single instance of a user which represents a single user and hence `id` simply refers to this instance user id:

```
class User {

    public $id = null;
```

Modify in this same `User` class the `create` method as well to grab the `lastInsertId` value from your db object instance:

```
public function create($fields) {
    if (!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account!');
    }

    $this->id = $this->_db->lastInsertId;

}
```

Then you can access the user ID in your `register.php` file simply accesing the user instance variable e.g. `$user->id` :

```
try {
    $user->create(array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
        'salt' => $salt,
        'firstname' => Input::get('first_name'),
        'lastname' => Input::get('last_name'),
        'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'group' => 1
    ));

    Session::flash('home', "You have registered with user ID $user->id");
    Redirect::to('index.php');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! Works perfectly and thanks for explaining how it works. One of my previous attempts were actually along those lines but I never made $lastInsertId public.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in the database class, here I named "lastInsertId". We use the function along with the PDO connection to get the last insert id.

```
class database{

    private $connection;

    private function connect()
    {
        $dsn = DB_DRIVER . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME;
        $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
    }
    
    // Define this function as public use in other class.
    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->connection->lastInsertID();
    }
}
```

We have used the PDO class to develop a method that returns us the lastInsertID, and that too without extending the database class to the PDO class.

Call the method when you need the last Insert Id from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

The insert() method of a database class should return insert id. Here is a relevant part for it:

```
public function insert ($table, $fields = array()) {
    $this->query($sql,$fields);
    return $this->_db->lastInsertId;
}
```

while create() method of a User class should create a user instance.

```
public function create($fields) {
    $id = $this->_db->insert('users', $fields);
    $this->find($id);
}
```

Note that insert() method is [vulnerable to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/lame_update).

And now you can use your newly created user all right

```
$user = new User();
$user->create(array(
  'username' => Input::get('username'),
  'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
  'firstname' => Input::get('first_name'),
  'lastname' => Input::get('last_name'),
  'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'group' => 1
  ));
echo $user->data['id'];
```

I hope you are looking not for the code to copy and paste but for the understanding. And I hope you understand the logic above.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still nothing return. You are correct though in that this is more about understanding than having it written. Things like the sql injection are my next steps once I have got the hang of getting what I want from classes.